# Why does combining a numerical sum and integral give a "non-numerical values" error?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am running this code:

```
TestInt[x_] := NSum[NIntegrate[1/(n t (E^t - 1)), {t, x, Infinity}], {n, 1, 10}]

TestInt[10]
```

and getting the error message:

> The integrand 1/((-1+E^t)\n\t) has evaluated to non-numerical values
>   for all sampling points in the region with boundaries
>   {{Infinity,10.}}.

It does give me an answer all the values I plug into TestInt, but they all come with this error message. Why? Can I trust the answers it is giving me, and how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: `int[x_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(n t (E^t - 1)), {t, x, Infinity}]`, then compute sum: `NSum[int[10, n], {n, 1, 10}]`. The problem is that `NIntegrate` and `NSum` require numerical arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> NSum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically.

It's the symbolic evaluation that produces the message.

The fix is to prevent symbolic input to `NIntegrate`:

```
f[n_Integer, x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(n t (E^t - 1)), {t, x, Infinity}]
TestInt[x_] := NSum[f[n, x], {n, 1, 10}
(* 0.0000121759 *)
```

It also occurs to me that you're really not using the power of `NSum` here. `NSum` works hard to enhance convergence of long/infinite sums: that's why it tries symbolic analysis first. To just add up a bunch of numbers, `Total` is simpler and faster.

```
TestInt[x_] := Total[Table[
  NIntegrate[1/(n t (E^t - 1)), {t, x, Infinity}], {n, 1, 10}]]
TestInt[10]
(* 0.0000121759 *)
```